# Node.js discord bot not saying goodbye message in server activity channel

Tags: node.js, discord, bots

I'm running node.js version 16.17.0 on macOS running Monterey. I have been building a bot a little at a time and I've gotten to the point where I am making it say hello and goodbye to users entering and leaving the server. The bot says hello to a new user and sends the embedded message (the user's avatar). When I leave the server with my alt account however it only sends the embedded message, not the farewell message that I have additionally. To be clear, the bot should send a hello message along with an embedded avatar picture when someone enters and should send a farewell message along with the embedded avatar when someone leaves but it only sends the avatar with no message for leaving.

I tried adding GUILD_PRESENCES to the intents that I call at the beginning but that runs me into the following error:

```
/Users/saisonxiang/genshi/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/BitField.js:168
    throw new RangeError(ErrorCodes.BitFieldInvalid, bit);
    ^

RangeError [BitFieldInvalid]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: undefined.
    at Function.resolve (/Users/saisonxiang/genshi/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/BitField.js:168:11)
    at /Users/saisonxiang/genshi/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/BitField.js:163:54
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.resolve (/Users/saisonxiang/genshi/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/BitField.js:163:40)
    at Client._validateOptions (/Users/saisonxiang/genshi/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:482:41)
    at new Client (/Users/saisonxiang/genshi/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:78:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/saisonxiang/genshi/index7.js:20:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32) {
  code: 'BitFieldInvalid'
}
```

I also tried moving the farewell message outside of the 'ready" statement, deleting and reinstalling the node_modules folder, and deleting and reinstalling node.js (as well as updating after reinstall).

I'm fairly stuck. Any help is appreciated. Here's the working code that just doesn't send the farewell message:

```
// Import Discord.js
const {
    Client,
    Collection,
    GatewayIntentBits,
    Partials,
    EmbedBuilder
} = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

// I like importing the intents and partials this way, just to make things a little more visible. 
// But the main things we're importing here are the Guild, and GuildMembers [PLURAL]
const { Guilds, GuildMembers, MessageContent, GuildMessages, GUILD_PRESENCES } = GatewayIntentBits;

// And here, we're importing the GuildMember [SINGULAR] for our Partials
const { User, Message, Channel, GuildMember } = Partials;

// Create Discord Client
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        Guilds,
        GuildMembers, // IMPORTANT
        GuildMessages,
        MessageContent,
    ],
    partials: [
        User,
        Channel,
        Message,
        GuildMember, // IMPORTANT
    ],
});

// When the client is ready, run this code (only once)
client.once('ready', () => {

// Adding the GuildMembers to our intents, and GuildMember to our partials allows for us to 
// receive the info we need for a welcome message; ei. when a member joins

// And lastly, when a member joins. I noticed you had the event inside your ready event, 
// but it needs to be outside the ready so be sure to double check that :)

client.on('guildMemberAdd', async (GuildMember) => {
console.log(GuildMember); // View the member data
    
await GuildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('1010768161349587035').send(`Well... ${GuildMember.user.username + "#" + GuildMember.user.discriminator} joined the server so I guess we will be okay`);

});

client.on('guildMemberAdd', guildMember =>{

    const embed7 = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setAuthor({name: `${guildMember.user.username}`, iconURL: guildMember.displayAvatarURL({dyanmic: true})})
    .setThumbnail(guildMember.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true}))
    guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('1010768161349587035').send({embeds: [embed7]})
});

client.on('GuildMemberRemove', async (GuildMember) => {
    console.log(GuildMember); // View the member data
        
    await GuildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('1010768161349587035').send(`Apparently ${GuildMember.user.username + "#" + GuildMember.user.discriminator} can't handle our bullshit anymore and decided to leave the server. They will be missed.`);
});

client.on('guildMemberRemove', guildMember => {
    const embed8 = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setAuthor({name: guildMember.user.username, iconURL: guildMember.displayAvatarURL({dyanmic: true})})
    .setThumbnail(guildMember.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true}))
    guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('1010768161349587035').send({embeds: [embed8]})
  });
})
            console.log('(。··)_且');

         

            // Login to Discord with your client's token
            client.login(token);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the `IntentBitfield` from discord import.

Reference: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#the-intents-bitfield